# How I can take a screenshot with current cursor in GNOME?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, screenshot

When I take a screenshot in Ubuntu 10.04 (Gnome) using application "Take Screenshot" I get a screenshow this a default mouse cursor, but when i take a screenshot, cursor of mouse was another, for instance, cursor of mouse, which happen when window is resizing. 
How i can do screenshot with current cursor mouse, but not default

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the combination PrintScr or Alt+PrintSc.

If this don't work, use [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) and configure the "Preferences > Advanced > Capture > Include cursor" options

enjoy!

Comment: For me it's always the default mouse cursor shown on the screenshot.

Comment: This does creates a "snapshot" sound in Gome, but it doesn't appear to do anything else. There's no file generated...

Comment: @Cerin please, review the folder ~ or ~/pictures as explained in the official documentation https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/screen-shot-record.html.en

Answer (score 2):

Try: `gnome-screenshot -p`

From the help:

`-p, --include-pointer          Include the pointer with the screenshot`

Comment: Note that this doesn't seem to work with a text select cursor, it just appears as a regular cursor.

Comment: @DanielImms Moreover, it always only displays a regular cursor.

Comment: Since you might be trying to take a screenshot of something other than the terminal window in which you issue the command, try the following to give you time to place the cursor: `sleep 5 && gnome-screenshot -p`

Answer (score 0):

Just found this:

[[ubuntu] Screenshot include mouse pointer? - ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1050026)

> Start `gconf-editor` and check `/apps/gnome-screenshot/include_pointer`

Seems to work for me with PrintScreen -> `gnome-screenshot`  ...